# Where to buy a second handed reliable motorcycle in Ho Chi Minh City in price aimed not for tourists?

Tags: vietnam

I need to buy a second handed, all functioning, reliable simple scooter (not more than 250cc I guess).

In HCMC, I often came across places with many motorcycles parking but it wasn't clear to me if it's a parking lot (as motorcycle parking lots are very common in HCMC) or a shop for second handed motorcycles.

I know of the straightforwardness of many Vietnamese people in doing business and of usually starting a sell with saying a quite expected and reasonable price beforehand and most often writing it clearly, so my problem is not about "how to buy a motorcycle in HCMC in a good price" but "how to recognize a good place to buy one", as one who doesn't speak fluent Vietnamese and at least for now cannot understand signage (which translation applications might mistranlate).

Where to buy a second handed reliable motorcycle in Ho Chi Minh City in price aimed not for tourists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many places to mention and they open and close like most people change underwear, the big plots you are talking about though are parking lots and not selling scooters.

The many many’s Torres that sell scooters are mostly smallish and can be found pretty much on every block in every district.

I always found that the best prices are found in district 2 or district 3 and that they do not vary much between stores in the same district.

Comment: I got to tell ya, I feel that for me a stranger, that about 26 years, almost always percepted motorcycle shops that were always, big, well furnished, with shiny and pricey motorcycles → these small shops you mention, I might grasped them as garages of some sort, when I passed across them.